# React Mui Autocomplete resets scroll after selecting values

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I'm trying to set up a *mui-autocomplete* component with additional buttons (Clear all (clear all values and close dropdown) + Apply (set value and close dropdown)) using *ListboxComponent*.

Issues:

1. when selecting options from the bottom of the list, the scroll position is reset to the top
2. cannot close the dropdown programmatically

Here is the *ListboxComponent*

```
        ListboxComponent={(listBoxProps) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <ul {...listBoxProps} />
              <div>
                <button
                  onMouseDown={(event) => {
                    // Disable blur
                    event.preventDefault();
                  }}
                  onClick={() => {
                    // clear values
                    setSelected([]);
                  }}
                >
                  Clear All
                </button>
                <button
                  onMouseDown={(event) => {
                    // Disable blur
                    event.preventDefault();
                  }}
                  onClick={() => {
                    // apply value
                  }}
                >
                  Apply
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
```

The options are rendered as follows:

```
        renderOption={(optionProps, option, optionState) => {
          return (
            <li {...optionProps}>
              <Checkbox
                icon={icon}
                checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                checked={optionState.selected}
              />
              {option}
            </li>
          );
        }}
```

So I'm using state to keep track of saving the selected values:

```
 const [selectedResult, setSelected] = useState([]);
```

And when the option is selected - the state is updated

```
        onChange={(event, selectedOptions) => {
          setSelected(selectedOptions);
        }}
```

But when the state changes, the component is re-rendered and the scroll is reset. It also seems that I can't use local variables to store the intermediate result, as the state won't update and the checkbox won't update.

[StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d485jh-htmem7?file=demo.js)

Is there anything I can do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the `ListboxComponent` inside a `React.useCallback`? This should solve the `jump to start` scroll glitch.

```js
<Autocomplete
  ListboxComponent={React.useCallback((listBoxProps) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul {...listBoxProps} />
        <div>
          // Rest of your code
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }, [])}
/>
```